# PCA error: Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r

I am trying to conduct PCA on my dataset and it gives me this error:

> Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Here is the code:

```
set.seed(1)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2) # loading the required packages
bank_train = read.csv('bankdata.csv') # bank training data
bank_test = read.csv('bank.full.csv') # bank test data
dim(bank_train)
dim(bank_test)
head(bank_test) # visualize the data set
names(bank_test)

bank_test.many = bank_test %>% select(age, job, marital, education,
                                      balance, housing, loan, contact,
                                      day, month, duration, campaign, 
                                      pdays, previous, poutcome, y)

# Principal Component Analysis using prcomp
bank_test.pca = prcomp(bank_test.many, center = TRUE, scale = TRUE)
```

Comment: Run `str(basnk_test.many)`.  Are any of the variables non-numeric?

Comment: yes, most of them are actually. Can you still conduct PCA?

Comment: No, you cannot.  That's exactly what the error is telling you: variables "must be numeric" (I'm quoting the error message here).